# What is the difference between signing a document, signing a transaction and signing a message? (very basic)

Tags: web3js, ethereumjs

As per my limited knowledge in Ethereum, user can sign the object(doc, Tx, msg) for the security purpose and with the public key other user can get that object.

But not understand the difference between them. We can use web3 to sign the object.

can anyone tell me what is these sign and what is the difference between signing document, transaction and message?

Thanks

Comment: They are mostly the same, there are some differences but they are very technical. See Yellow Paper appendix F "Signing transactions"